# Infinite loop to be killed when channel receives new value

Tags: go, channel

I have 2 modules(module1 and module2) where I am generating some random numbers in module1 and passing the same to module2 via a channel defined in main. When the values land in module 2, I want it to be printed in a loop until new values arrive again from module1. Here is the code.

`main.go` file content

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "example/module1"
    "example/module2"
)

func main() {
    ints := make(chan []int, 1)
    for {
        select {
        case <- time.After(5 * time.Second):
            go module1.GenerateRandint(ints)
        case  <- module2.Done:
            go module2.Start(ints)
        }
    }
}
```

Contents of `module1` is as follows.

```
package module1

import (
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func GenerateRandint(a chan []int){
    var rint []int
    for  i:=0;i<1;i++ {
        rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
        rint = append(rint,  rand.Int())
    }
    a <- rint
}
```

`module2` is:

```
package module2

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var Done = make(chan struct{})
var quit = make(chan struct{})

type localData struct {
    nums []int
    Lock sync.RWMutex
}

var store localData

func init() {
    go func() {
        Done <- struct{}{}
        quit <- struct{}{}
    }()
    go printer(0, quit)
}

func printer(id int, quit chan struct{}) {

    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            return
        default:
            store.Lock.RLock()
            fmt.Println("ID:", id, "====", store.nums)
            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
            store.Lock.RUnlock()

        }
    }
}

func Start(a chan []int) {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    d := <-a
    fmt.Println("RECEIVED DATA", d)
    store.Lock.Lock()
    go func() {
        quit <- struct{}{}
    }()
    store.nums = d
    store.Lock.Unlock()
    go printer(rand.Int(), quit)
    Done <- struct{}{}

}
```

In the final output, I do not see the `printer` function continuously printing the slice. It prints it once. I am pasting a sample output below.

```
ID: 0 ==== []
RECEIVED DATA [5183630848712612481]
ID: 2057228961822266542 ==== [5183630848712612481]
RECEIVED DATA [7203870927705193095]
RECEIVED DATA [1478549829208931483]
ID: 2311909806311895805 ==== [1478549829208931483]
RECEIVED DATA [3000658591728341557]
```

The ideal output should have been:

```
ID: 0 ==== []
RECEIVED DATA [5183630848712612481]
ID: 2057228961822266542 ==== [5183630848712612481]
ID: 2057228961822266542 ==== [5183630848712612481]
ID: 2057228961822266542 ==== [5183630848712612481]
ID: 2057228961822266542 ==== [5183630848712612481]
ID: 2057228961822266542 ==== [5183630848712612481]
RECEIVED DATA [7203870927705193095]
ID: 3052382001843759201 ==== [7203870927705193095]
ID: 3052382001843759201 ==== [7203870927705193095]
ID: 3052382001843759201 ==== [7203870927705193095]
ID: 3052382001843759201 ==== [7203870927705193095]
ID: 3052382001843759201 ==== [7203870927705193095]
RECEIVED DATA [1478549829208931483]
ID: 3850200927174591249 ==== [1478549829208931483]
ID: 3850200927174591249 ==== [1478549829208931483]
ID: 3850200927174591249 ==== [1478549829208931483]
ID: 3850200927174591249 ==== [1478549829208931483]
ID: 3850200927174591249 ==== [1478549829208931483]
RECEIVED DATA [3000658591728341557]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are asking the question about the call to `go printer(0, quit)` in the `init()` function. The reason it is printing the entire list only once is because of the following:

In the init() function, you are trying to send data to both `Done` and `quit` channels. Now, they will obviously block until a receiver is ready. When the modules are loaded, the receiver is not ready and hence you go to the `default` case in the printer method. Therefore, it prints the statement once and goes to sleep for 500 milliseconds. During that time, the `main()` starts up and creates a receiver for the `Done` channel. This unblocks writing to this channel and subsequently writes to the `quit` channel as well. Now, since `quit` also has data, the select statement in the `printer` method simply returns without printing any more.

Comment: Thanks for replying. for the sake of brevity, I am going to keep in very short and direct. The first assumption is wrong. The end goal is to get data like mentioned in "expected output" area of my question. There are 2 things . I do not printer continuously printing the default section. It prints it only once. second issue is, if you notice the output I had pasted, it skips some values received via the channels and does not print it at all. I wanted to know what is happening there as well.  I want to know if this is the idiomatic way of achieving this goal. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot kill a goroutine: there is no `kill` or `murder` function.  Even if there were one, there is no *name* for a goroutine—no user-accessible thread-ID, as it were.  So the only way to kill *one specific* goroutine is to murder *all* goroutines, by destroying the entire world with a nuclear blast, e.g., via [`os.Exit`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit) or returning from `main`.

A goroutine *can* exit on its own, gracefully, by returning from its initial function or by calling [`runtime.Goexit`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Goexit).<sup>1</sup>  So what you will need to do is arrange for your loop to stop on its own:

> I have 2 modules (module1 and module2) where I am generating some random numbers in module1 and passing the same to module2 via a channel defined in main. When the values land in module 2, I want it to be printed in a loop until new values arrive again from module1.

Your actual code seems very oddly structured.  For instance, signaling that something is "done" in Go is often handled with a channel that's simply *closed*, rather than having data sent on it:

```
doneChan := make(chan struct{})
// ...
close(doneChan) // tell everyone we are done
```

This works especially well because the close event is, in effect, broadcast to multiple channel readers:

```
doneChan := make(chan struct{})
go f1(doneChan)
go f2(doneChan)
// ...
go fN(doneChan)
// ...
close(doneChan) // tells f1, f2, ..., fN we are done
```

Your `main` could use such a thing to tell *both* modules to quit, for instance.

That aside, it seems to me that the logical arrangement would go like this ([see complete Playground version](https://play.golang.org/p/tmboX2kZHyF)).  We start with a generating function that has only one responsibility: generate a slice of random numbers and send it, quitting when told to quit:

```golang
// it's not clear why `a` is `[]int` when there is only one
func GenerateRandints(a chan<- []int, done <-chan struct{}) {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for {
        rint := []int{rand.Int()}
        select {
        case a <- rint:
        case <-done:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Then we have a function that uses these, in a loop, until told to quit.  It also indicates when it's actually done via a `sync.WaitGroup` so that its invoker can tell when it is truly done.  Note that I removed all the global variables and fancy `init` functions and the mutex.  Presumably, in the real code, these had some purpose, and you may need to put some or all of them back.

(Your example spawned one `Printer` function with ID zero, and another with a random number ID.  I kept the `fmt.Println` and simply hardcoded the zero here.)

```golang
func UseRandints(wg *sync.WaitGroup, a <-chan []int, done <-chan struct{}) {
    defer wg.Done()
    var r []int
    for {
        select {
        case r = <-a:
        case <-done:
            return
        default:
            if r != nil {
                fmt.Println("ID:", 0, "====", r)
            }
            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, we need a `main` to drive the action.  I made one up here; your real one will no doubt be different:

```golang
func main() {
    ints := make(chan []int)
    done := make(chan struct{})
    go GenerateRandints(ints, done)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go UseRandints(&wg, ints, done)

    // wait 5 seconds then tell everyone to quit
    <-time.After(5 * time.Second)
    close(done)
    // wait for UseRandints() to signal that it's done
    wg.Wait()
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that there are some subtle differences between calling `runtime.Goexit` and simply returning.  Turning this into a [complete program](https://play.golang.org/p/3Q7GRWiyp9L) shows the effect (though technically there is a race here):

```
func main() {
    go f1()
    runtime.Goexit()
}

func f1() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("f1 finished")
    runtime.Goexit()
}
```

When this program is run in the Go playground, it waits for one second, prints `f1 finished`, then terminates with a runtime exception (`fatal error: no goroutines (main called runtime.Goexit) - deadlock!`) because all goroutines have exited.

[Commenting out the `runtime.Goexit()` call in `main` produces a program that behaves differently](https://play.golang.org/p/xRD_cEPPyMi): this program exits immediately, without printing `f1 finished` and without any runtime errors.  That is because calling `runtime.Goexit()` means we never go through the "kill all other goroutines" code path that a return from `main` does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By kill, i meant some way to kill the earlier loop. I worked around it by modifying the module2's init function. I started the printer function from the init of module2 and continuously looped over the store variable. Will share the output here for anyone who is interested in improving/figuring the answer to the above question. Thank you

Comment: You have to tell the Go routine "please quit", and then it has to obey. As long as you're *writing* the Go routine yourself, you can code it to do that. How (and when and why) to tell it to quit is up to you, but "close a `done` channel" is a common Go idiom.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by modifying the main and module2

main.go

```
var ints = make(chan map[string]int)

func init() {
    go module2.Start(ints)
}

func main() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
            go module1.GenerateRandint(ints)
        }
    }
}
```

Module2 file was changed to look like this.

```
type Myint int

var Data = make(chan map[string]Myint)
var fetch = make(chan map[string]Myint)

type localData struct {
    nums map[string]int
    Lock sync.RWMutex
}

var store localData

func init() {
    go loopover()
}

func loopover() {
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                v, k := <-fetch
                if !k {
                    return
                }
                fmt.Println(v)

            }
        }()
    }
    for {

        for i, v := range store.nums {
            tmp := make(map[string]Myint)
            tmp[i] = Myint(v)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            fetch <- tmp
        }
    }
}

func Start(a chan map[string]int) {
    for {
        select {
        case d := <-a:
            fmt.Println("RECEIVED", d)
            store.Lock.Lock()
            store.nums = d
            store.Lock.Unlock()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop in the top half of `loopover` is very odd: it spins off two separate goroutines that try, repeatedly, to read from the `fetch` channel. These read until the channel is closed (the `!k` test) ... but it's never closed: there is no `close(fetch)` anywhere. That's not wrong in Go, you can leave a goroutine around forever, but it just seems odd to spin off *two* of them then have them compete for read-and-print, and check for closed-ness when nobody closes.

Comment: Meanwhile, there is a data race in the second half. The inner `for` loop runs over `store.nums` (evaluating it once before entering the loop) but does not lock against function `Start`, which writes to `store.nums` under a lock. You'll want to either get the `store.nums` value under a lock, or avoid this sort of communicate-by-sharing-memory (the `store.nums` variable) method.

Comment: Last, the `select` in `Start` is now pointless, as there is only one thing ever to do. You might as well use `for d := range a` here. Nobody ever does a `close(a)` either so this loop is infinite as well, but that's a compact and Go-like way to write it. You could use the same idiom in the two anonymous goroutines.